# How to elect position of new item output in a dropdown when using add_filter

Tags: filters, hooks, dropdown

Hello I am using the suggested snippet here to add a new term to a dropdown menu:
https://wpjobmanager.com/document/applications-customising-application-statuses/

which is:

```
add_filter( 'job_application_statuses', 'add_new_job_application_status' );

function add_new_job_application_status( $statuses ) {
    $statuses['example'] = _x( 'Example', 'job_application', 'wp-job-manager- 
applications' );
    return $statuses;
}
```

That works fine but my new single entry 'example' is output at the bottom of the dropdown list, I'd really like it to be in 2nd place. Is there a simple way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't believe this is a WP question, but a general PHP question about arrays, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353745/how-to-insert-element-into-arrays-at-specific-position

Comment: Thanks Tom, I wasn't aware if there might be nuances to executing this in a Wordpress functions.php file for this WP Job Manager plugin Applications add-on. Sunny's solution below works well though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function in conjunction with [array_merge()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). Here is an example:

```
function add_new_job_application_status( $statuses ) {
  return array_merge(
    array_splice( $statuses, 0, 1 ),
    array( 'example' => _x( 'Example', 'job_application', 'wp-job-manager- 
applications' ) ),
    array_splice( $statuses, 1, -1 ) 
  );
}
add_filter( 'job_application_statuses', 'add_new_job_application_status' );
```

This function takes the first item in the `$statuses` array, your custom example field, the rest of the items in the array and merges it together. You need to do it this way as splice doesn't support inserting a multi-dimensional array at a specific point in an array. Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent, new to me and concise code. I see this can be used to replace or just insert an additional entry which is great. Thanks.